# Replacing values in multiple columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataset, data-cleaning, categorical-data

for example consider this dataframe :

```
dam <- data.frame(name = letters[1:5],
                      re1 = factor(c("yes","no","yes","no","yes")),
                      re2 = factor(c("yes","no","yes","no","yes")),
                      re3 = factor(c("yes","no","yes","no","yes")))

#>the dataframe looks like this 
     name re1 re2 re3
      a   yes yes yes
      b   no  no  no
      c   yes yes yes
      d   no  no  yes
      e   yes no  yes
```

I would like to replace the yes & no's in re1,re3 with 1 & 2.
to get something like this -

```
 #>the output should look like this 
     name re1 re2 re3
      a   1   1   yes
      b   2   2   no
      c   1   1   yes
      d   2   2   no
      e   1   1   yes
```

I know i could do something like :

```
replace_re <- c("yes","no","yes","no","yes")
with_this <- rep(1:2,2,5)
dam$re1 %>% mapvalues(replace_re,with_this)
dam$re2 %>% mapvalues(replace_re,with_this)
```

and I know I could use a for loop for many columns.

but what I want is how do you accomplish this in a functional way ,say with pacakage "purrr" (map,invoke_map functions)and does the job,in an elegant way for n such columns
i.e replacing my categorical variables with some other values.

also, how would I do that with base R apply functions ? 
this might be a very trivial question but I'm unable to come up with a more tidy way of doing this.

Recoding the factors seems to be a bane for me,any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: Apart from the typo (res2 and res3 in your data, re2 in your code) its not clear what you are trying to do. You should also state which packages you are using (plyr for `mapvalues` *and* dplyr for the pipe?). And why do you pass `mapvalues` a vector like that? The first vector should be unique values and the second should be the same length, eg `mapvalues(this, c("small","big"),c("tiny","fat"))`. Finally, what do you want to do with the values once you've mapped them, because here you are just printing them. Do you want them back in the data frame? And what's wrong with a loop?

Comment: corrected my typos,sorry. basically, I have a huge dataset ,of which there are many  categorical variables ,with Likert-type scale, but encoded as numbers (1:5) and I would like to write a function which changes the encoded numbers into the Likert-type scale,for all the columns where such encodings exist .how do I do that ? I know we can do it with 'purrr' package, but I'm not sure how.there's nothing wrong with for loop but I'd like to do it in a functional programming way.

Comment: Do you only want to replace re1 and re2? Because that's what you've got in " #>the output should look like this". My answer replaces all three. What's the criterion for replacing a column? All except the last one? All columns given a set of names? Or did you really mean all of them?

Comment: a function that takes the columns of a dataframe that I give as an input and maps the new values onto old values,just in those columns ,is what I'm trying to figure out ,without using loops .we can do something like it with "Purrr" package,but not sure how to .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
> dam
  name re1 re2 re3
1    a yes yes yes
2    b  no  no  no
3    c yes yes yes
4    d  no  no  no
5    e yes yes yes
```

do this:

```
dam2 = reshape2::dcast(
   dplyr::mutate(
      reshape2::melt(dam,id.var="name"),
      value=plyr::mapvalues(
           value, c("yes","no"),c("OK","notOK"))
   ),name~variable)
```

get that:

```
> dam2
  name   re1   re2   re3
1    a    OK    OK    OK
2    b notOK notOK notOK
3    c    OK    OK    OK
4    d notOK notOK notOK
5    e    OK    OK    OK
```

I've recoded it to "OK" and "notOK" because your remapping doesn't make sense. The "from values" should be unique, not have repeated "yes" and "no" in them.

Note how this is done. Make a tidy data set by melting. Mutate it. Cast it back into untidy format. Yes you could use pipes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you want. Do you want an *elegant* solution using available packages and no for loops? Or, do you just want something that works?

The following is a solution I wrote before I knew about plyr / dplyr and used the car package's recode function. It works, but it's not what I would call elegant. You'll probably want to read the documentation on car::recode, as its syntax is a bit odd.

Now that I've migrated over to the Hadleyverse / tidyverse, though, I'll probably figure out a solution that uses dplyr's recode function instead. But until then, this works for me.

```
library(car)

recode2 <- function ( data, fields, recodes, as.factor.result = FALSE ) {
  for ( i in which(names(data) %in% fields) ) { # iterate over column indexes that are present in the passed dataframe that are also included in the fields list
    data[,i] <- car::recode( data[,i], recodes, as.factor.result = as.factor.result )
  }
  data
}
```

So,

```
dam <- data.frame(name = letters[1:5],
  re1 = factor(c("yes","no","yes","no","yes")),
  re2 = factor(c("yes","no","yes","no","yes")),
  re3 = factor(c("yes","no","yes","no","yes")))

recode2(dam, fields = c('re1', 're2'), recodes = "'yes' = 1; 'no' = 2", as.factor.result = TRUE)
```

Results in:

```
  name re1 re2 re3
1    a   1   1 yes
2    b   2   2  no
3    c   1   1 yes
4    d   2   2  no
5    e   1   1 yes
```

Comment: thank you,I know I can make it work with for loops,but I was thinking about using something within the 'Tidyverse' and do it ,in a functional style .